# How to "Hello World!" RCS Messaging?

Tags: messaging

I have read the "RCS Universal Profile Service Definition Document" by GSMA, to be more specific Version 2.3 from "06 December 2018".

Such a new technology that I have no idea how to start developing for this.

So far I believe:

1. "You need to have an RCS capable client (either Samsung integrated RCS capability or Google Jibe messaging app)".
2. "Your operator needs to be RCS ready"

I want at least to send 1 RCS Message from my own app to my phone. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Below is code to send RCS Message ===> Hello World

```json
{
   "RCSMessage": {
       "textMessage": "hello world"
   },
   "messageContact": {
       "userContact": "+14251234567"
   }
}
```